# How to add Storyboard headerview to tableview created at initialization by UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6, interface-builder

I have a subclass of UITableViewController.

By default, it creates a `UITableView` when it is initialized. To that tableview I have set a header that I created in Interface Builder in the screen that is controlled by the controller. The header has two buttons:

one to enter editing mode for the tableview (called "Edit")

one to add a random item to the tableview (called "New").

I linked an `IBOutlet` property called `headerView` to the header from Interface Builder and I set it to be the header of the `UITableView` created at initialization in the `viewDidLoad` method.

The problem is that when I press the "New" button (which adds a new row with a new item to the tableview) the header of the tableview falls down to the bottom of the tableview.

Any idea why? How can I make it stick to the top?

This is the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
    }
```

This is the method that gets executed when the "New" button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender {
    Item *newItem = [[ItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
    NSInteger lastRow = [[[ItemStore sharedStore] allItems] indexOfObject:newItem];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}
```

[image: From this point the header stays at the bottom of the tableview][image: This is a screenshot of the header when the tableview is empty]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you've set up the layout for table header view in a wrong way. Was there any layout constraint on it?

By the way, [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/dobaduc/stackoverflow-32569242) is a very simple example to demonstrate how simply it is to achieve what you want in the storyboard. It will produce the result like below:

[image]

Please use this project to compare with your current configuration. 
I hope this helps in one way or another.

Comment: Yes. This is what I intended to do. The only constraints I set are for the two buttons to stick to the top left & right corners. Another thing I should mention is that in Interface builder the `UIView` upon which the two buttons are placed does not fill the whole screen. It's just a small portion at the top of the screen. The rest of the screen is empty (it gets filled when the tableview is created at the initialization of the `UITableViewController`).

Comment: Hmm... Without seeing your code & configuration on the interface builder I am afraid that I can't help

Comment: Ok. I'll check out the github link. If I am unable to figure it out I'll tell you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked. Had to delete the headerView property and rely only on the storyboard. It seems that I was overdoing things. Thanks again.